# How to add @mention in trix editor with react js?

Tags: reactjs, rich-text-editor, trix

In react, trix editor doesnt support functionality of @mention
I have made here a simple version of it here below can anyone help me and try to add filter in it and use of arrow keys because trix doesn't support onKeyUp and onKeyDown

states and refrences

```
  // jsx
  const [trixData, setTrixData] = useState({ name: '', pageData: { text: '', html: '' } })
  const [mentions, setMentions] = useState([])
  const [showDropdown, setShowDropdown] = useState(false)
  const [mentionSuggestions, setMentionSuggestions] = useState([])
  const trixEditorRef = useRef(null)
```

handleEditorChange is onChange method used for trixEditor

```
 const handleEditorChange = (html, text) => {
setTrixData((prev) => ({
  ...prev,
  pageData: { text: text, html: html },
}))
const cursorPosition = trixEditorRef.current.editor.getSelectedRange()[0]

const typedChar = cursorPosition > 0 ? text[cursorPosition - 1] : ''
if (typedChar === '@') {
  setShowDropdown(true)
  //  const typedName = text.substring(cursorPosition)
  //  const matchingAdmins = mentions.filter((adminName) =>
  //    adminName.toLowerCase().startsWith(typedName.toLowerCase()),
  //  )
  setMentionSuggestions(mentions)
} else {
  setShowDropdown(false)
  setMentionSuggestions([])
}
}
```

handleMentionSelect if the function responsible for adding @mention in trixEditor field

```
const handleMentionSelect = (adminName) => {
 const currentEditor = trixEditorRef.current.editor
 const cursorPosition = currentEditor.getSelectedRange()[0]
 const mentionText = `${adminName} `
 currentEditor.insertString(mentionText, cursorPosition)
 const newCursorPosition = cursorPosition + mentionText.length
 currentEditor.setSelectedRange(newCursorPosition, 0)
 setMentionSuggestions([])
 setShowDropdown(false)
 currentEditor.element.focus()
}

// html
<CCol md={12}>
      <input id="x" type="hidden" name="content" ref={contentEl} />

      <TrixEditor
        onChange={handleEditorChange}
        placeholder="editor's placeholder"
        value={trixData.pageData.html}
        input="x"
        ref={trixEditorRef}
      />
    </CCol>
```

dropdown menu that shows mentions

```
    {showDropdown && (
      <div id="mention-suggestions">
        {mentionSuggestions.map((adminName, index) => (
          <div
            key={index}
            className="mention-suggestion"
            onClick={() => handleMentionSelect(adminName)}
          >
            {adminName}
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    )}
```